# Except in a regex still returns a match

Tags: regex

I am in the process of trying to firm my grasp over regex expression using except and am trying to explain to myself why the following wont work. I am using regex 101 for testing

I have something like this

```
[^abc]s$
```

This works when any letter that is next to the end letter s is not an a,b or c.
What i want is the entire string should not have an a , b or c. How can i specify that.

I tried this

```
([^abc].*)s$
. => any character
* => any no of times
s$ => ending with a s character
```

so `[^abc].` should be any character except abc - Am i Correct ?

Overall the expression should be any no of characters except characters a,b or c occurring any no of times and ending with character s ? I tried this and this still passes the regex  with the following word

```
ddsbbsdds
```

since the string has the characters b in it it should have failed the regex test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a (potential) *partial* match. You specify what should match the end anchor of your test string, but not what the start should be. Also, you are testing just a single character, because a custom character class `[...]` only tests one.

To test an entire string, from start to end, add a start anchor `^`:

```
^[^abc]s$
```

This will only match two-character strings, so to allow more occurrences of the custom character class, add either `*` (zero or more) or `+` (one or more):

```
^[^abc]+s$
```

This will match entire strings, not containing `a`, `b` or `c`, and always end with an `s`. ([See this on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wP6aQ6/2).)

(Note on your own attempts: `[^abc].` fails because `[^abc]` matches a single character and the next `.` matches *any* character. Adding parentheses and `*` are random attempts to "make it work", as far as I can see.)

Comment: Thank you for answering. Could you tell me why my `([^abc].*)s$` fails. Did i interpret this expression wrong ? I mean even you read it the way it is I would think it should fail as it specifies any characters the preceed s should not be a,b or c

Comment: @JamesFranco: the `.` will match any character, thus violating your rule of "no a,b,c". The only criterium here is that the *first* character is not one of `abc` – and since you did not add a start anchor, that 'first' can actually be *any* character in the string.